# How to insert N+1 new lines after each line of a file with sed

Tags: command-line, sed

I want to change this:

```
This is line1
This is line2
This is line3
```

To

```
This is line1
InsertedLine
This is line2
InsertedLine
InsertedLine
This is line3
InsertedLine
InsertedLine
InsertedLine
```

I.e. new line should be inserted once after first line in original text, twice after second line, thrice after third line and so on.

Comment: Why `sed` specifically? is this a homework assignment? It would be straightforward in something like `awk` or `perl` where you have programmatic access to the line/record index (and - in the case of perl - string multiplication).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

- prime the hold space with your desired `InsertedLine`; I'm not sure the best way to do this but one option is to swap the 1st line pattern space into the hold buffer, replace the (now empty) pattern space with `InsertedLine`, then swap back:

  ```
   1{x;s/^/InsertedLine/;x}
  ```
- now proceed by appending the hold space to the pattern space, printing the result, then stripping everything up to the last `InstertedLine` and appending that back to the hold space:

  ```
   G;p;s/.*\n//;H
  ```

so that the hold space gets a new `InsertedLine` appended to it each time.

So given

```
$ cat file
This is line1
This is line2
This is line3
```

then

```
$ sed -n -e '1{x;s/^/InsertedLine/;x}' -e 'G;p;s/.*\n//;H' file
This is line1
InsertedLine
This is line2
InsertedLine
InsertedLine
This is line3
InsertedLine
InsertedLine
InsertedLine
```

---

Of course, non-sed options may be simpler ex.

```
awk '{for(i=0;i<FNR;i++) $0 = $0 ORS "InstertedLine"}1' file
```

or

```
perl -pe 's/$/"\nInstertedLine" x $./e' file
```